# Cannot run control.py in order to find IP

Tags: circuit, ip-address

I am following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777192/how-do-i-get-the-tor-exit-node-ip-address-over-the-control-port) in order to find the **tor exit node IP**.

Running the proposed script ( see below), I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/.rot//ip.py", line 6, in <module>
    for circ in controller.get_circuits():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 414, in wrapped
    raise exc
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not
```

**What is the origin of this error and what should be changed for this script to work?**

My control port is open I can access it with `telnet`.

---

PS: full script

```
from stem import CircStatus
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()

  for circ in controller.get_circuits():
    if circ.status != CircStatus.BUILT:
      continue

    exit_fp, exit_nickname = circ.path[-1]

    exit_desc = controller.get_network_status(exit_fp, None)
    exit_address = exit_desc.address if exit_desc else 'unknown'

    print "Exit relay"
    print "  fingerprint: %s" % exit_fp
    print "  nickname: %s" % exit_nickname
    print "  address: %s" % exit_address
    print
```

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py` (from which the error come from)

```
   409            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
   410          except Exception as exc:
   411            default = get_default(func, args, kwargs)
   412  
   413            if default == UNDEFINED:
   414              raise exc
   415            else:
   416              return default
   417      else:
   418        @functools.wraps(func)
   419        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Pretty sure what you've given us isn't an accurate representation of your script since the line numbers don't match.

Comment: Can you have a brief look at new file where the error is originating. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply reinstalled `stem` from the [git repository](https://git.torproject.org/stem.git) to solve the issue.

The previous installation was realized with

```
# apt-get install python-stem
```

on `Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21)`. Another package may have been forgotten.

Comment: lol kali linux skiddies :D

Answer (score 0):

You have your system settings wrong, pehaps: it works like a copy-and-paste for me:

```
# python -V
Python 2.7.9

# python getexit.py
Exit relay

fingerprint: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
nickname: nickname-scrubbled
address: 1.2.3.4-scrubbled
Exit relay
fingerprint: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
nickname: nickname2-scrubbled
address: 5.6.7.8-scrubbled
```

Are you sure you're using the latest Stem library? Mine is:

```
 # pip list | grep stem
 stem (1.4.0)
```

Comment: My version is Python `2.7.12+`

Comment: and the stem library? do you use a non-english locale in your linux/unix account?

Comment: I found a substitute command: `echo -e 'AUTHENTICATE "p"\r\nsignal\ngetinfo circuit-status\r\nQUIT' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051`

Comment: yes, but it's a shellscript(that I actually, prefer). The problem is, that your Python may have a problem that will appear not just there. Try to set LC_ALL to en_US.UTF-8 like in [this tutorial](https://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment) and try it